# How to change a row to component on Angular Material Table?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-components

I have a relatively simple angular material table in my application. I am populating it with a dataSource. I have a boolean flag which is named isActive,

I want to change rows into a column spanned card component (or any other material component which is okay to the task) with a message like "This row is not usable atm!" when isActive flag set false for that row.

Can't see anything related to this on both stack, blitz or angular.io. I appreciate your effort and thank you in advance.

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="businessId">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let course"> {{course.businessId}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

     ...........More rows in between

 <ng-container matColumnDef="isActive">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> d </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let course"> {{course.isActive}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
   <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"> </mat-row>
```

Comment: A naive and not so "Angular-ish" solution is to have `ngIf=course.isActive` template and `else` template in each column. Choose one column (the leftmost?) to host the template that says "This row is not usable atm!" when `course.isActive` resolves to `false`. And style this template to spill over other columns as needed. The template of the rest of the columns should be blank in that case. A more advanced solution may involve dynamic component loading as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Comment: @Benny thank you for your time and answer mate. Looking for more nativeish solution but I'll give you a heads-up after trying your method.